# Why are fractal antennas able to receive so many more frequencies than a conventional one?

Tags: antenna, physics

Why is it that so much more different values of frequencies can be received by a fractal antenna than a conventional one? Is it because of the self-similarity, when you look at different scales of the antenna pattern? What´s the physics behind it?

Comment: I don't understand the question - can someone explain it?

Comment: @descheleschilder Your English doesn't have to be perfect, people here forgive awkward wording and tricky grammar gotchas. But words with missing letters suggest you really were a bit hasty.

Comment: @Andyaka A normal antenna has a much smaller range of frequencies they can receive than a fractal antenna. And I´m asking why that is.

Comment: Perhaps with antennas you should be talking (and thinking) in terms of wavelengths rather than frequencies (and yes, I do know the terms are related).

Comment: A spiral antenna has very wide bandwidth so what is your real question given that almost every assertion you have made (in your question) has been somewhat objected to? Best practice - try to avoid assertions in questions.

Comment: Read this - it poo-poos fractal antennas and provides hard evidence (apparently): http://www.antenna-theory.com/antennas/fractal.php

Comment: @descheleschilder Have you read this article: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2215098615000026  It shows how "fractal-like modifications" to a standard path antenna enhances its bandwidth and allowing it to be used over over a wider frequency range. Is what you're asking: *How does this work ?* Well you see that they just try something and see what comes out. Antenna design is a lot of trial-and-error as EM behavior can be complex. I still doubt this antenna would be any good in a cellphone as it does not suppress that what you **do not** want to receive (like an interferer).

Comment: A fractal antenna is susceptible to much more radio frequencies than a normal antenna. Can you imagine a cell phone with dozens of normal antennas attached to it?

Comment: @FakeMoustache That what´s tuning is for.

Comment: Do you assume that it is **more** sensitive to a certain frequency than a non-fractal antenna designed for the same frequency would be ? Why would a cellphone need a dozen antennas ? Usually about 4 or 5 is enough.

Comment: *That what´s tuning is for* tuning what ? The antenna cannot be tuned as it is fixed.

Comment: By tuning, I don't mean tuning the antenna but picking out the desired radio wave, like in a radio.

Comment: Sure, but if you leave all the supression of the interferers to the receiver then that places more stringent requirements on it especially on dynamic range. Do you want your GPS to stop working when someone near you is using their phone and their UMTS signal is saturation your receiver ? No you don't. So that is why separate antennas are used so the GPS antenna can filter out that UMTS signal so GPS reception is not hindered.

Comment: Some research can be found [here](http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:840332/FULLTEXT02) - see page 33. By this paper, the most common antenna types are planar monopole and planar inverted-F antennas.

Comment: @Andyaka In the experiment you referred to, there are only five iterations used. Far too less to come to a solid conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

*" fractal antennas are used in cell phones"*

That is a **bold** statement. I would say *"some cellphones use fractal antennas"* and *"Some fractal antennas are used in cellphones"*. Most antennas I have seen on cellphones are more traditional types like pifa or microstrip.

All antennas have a certain frequency band or maybe several bands in which they are most sensitive. It is a result of the design of the antenna.

**All** signals can be seen as a combination of sinewaves with each a certain frequency. Depending on the frequency characteristic of the antenna the antenna will pick-up that frequency better or worse than some other frequency. This is not a property that only fractal antennas have. All antennas behave this way. Some antennas are more broadband, some are more selective.

Comment: Then why they use fractal antennas? I think because modern cell phones make use of so many frequencies to which for wich only one normal antenna isn´t enough. But that was not my question. My question was how a fractal antenna can receive so many frequencies. And by the way, most modern cell phones dó use them.

Comment: A fractal antenna only has to be very broadband to allow it to receive many frequencies. But that sounds like a compromise to me. You can usually get better performance using an antenna designed for a certain frequency band. *"And by the way, most modern cell phones dó use them"* OK, then show me some proof to convince me that that is the case. When I Google for fractal antennas I mostly see antennas that are too large to fit in a cellphone.

Comment: Google for fractal `antennas and cell phones`. The fractal antenna  used is made up of squares, decreasing in size and its form is scale independent (as should be in fractals). But again this isn´t an answer to my question, only a doubt about an unimportant part of my question.

Comment: Then state your question properly. Not in the comments but in the question (use edit). Googled that, it returns some articles of ancient phones using a fractal-ish antenna. I'm still not convinced that fractal antennas are more than a niche solution.

Comment: Believe me, it´s the ónly solution.

Comment: Stop making such statements that prove you have little understanding of mobile communications, transceivers and antennas. Unless you can provide hard evidence of course (scientific article, patent or whatever). Which I have not seen yet. Sofar I have only seen evidence that vote against your claims.

Comment: I want an answer to my question, wich I haven´t seen yet.               @Fakemoustache Look here: https://youtu.be/3Xq6h31UCKQ

Comment: Or here https://youtu.be/Zpy0qGBDQq0

Comment: The first one looks like a promotional video from a company that makes fractal antennas. So of course they say it's the best thing since sliced bread was invented. The second shows that a fractal design increases the bandwidth, which no one denies. That still doesn't mean it is the solution for everything. You have to understand that receiving **as many signals as possible** is not always a good thing. For some niche applications it can be. For most it is not.

Comment: But that sill doesn't answer my answer: why do fractal antennas have such a broad band of frequencies they can receive? What´s the physics behind it, regardless if there´s a small niche of applications.

Comment: I guess it has to do with the special shape of those antennas. Normal antennas are sensitive at 1/4, 1/2 and 1 times the wavelength of the signal. In a fractal antenna there is probably always a certain path that has this length or a length close to it. See it as a combination of many antennas of different lengths combined.

Comment: Now that´s a useful answer!!

Comment: Fractals have an infinite length. In theory. In practice, this is impossible to realize, but the length can be made very long. So, considering the remark of FakeMoustache, the fractal antenna is sensitive to 1, 1/2,1/4,1/8,1/16,... times the wavelength. I answered my own question!